# Can I receive some data from the entire video and selectively control the rest?

Tags: javascript, video, browser, controls, buffering

I want the user to receive some data from the entire video and selectively control the rest.
Is there a way for the browser to handle only the specific buffering of the full video?
In other words, is it possible to limit the range of media sources that the browser will buffer in the entire video?

*Additional explanation


I request video / mp4 type video data at javascript.

And it is inserted into the browser as a `<video>` tag.


At this point, I wonder if there is a way to limit the amount of buffer that the browser can hold.

In other words, I would like to know if there is a way to limit the buffer capacity that is stored in the browser at one time, and to stop the playback of the video and the data loading when the capacity is exceeded.


I found '[HTMLMediaElement.mozFrameBufferLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Properties)'.

However, this is already a deprecated property, meaning 'the amount of storage at one time'.*

Comment: `receive some data from the entire video` what kind of data?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy
I mean a part of the video file (for example, if the entire video is 10 seconds, only 3 seconds are downloaded)

Comment: I find the question interesting but it's not properly explained. Please try to explain it as much as you can by editing your question.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy

I request video/mp4 type video data at javascript. And it is inserted into the browser as a <video> tag.

At this point, I wonder if there is a way to limit the amount of buffer that the browser can hold.
In other words, I would like to know if there is a way to limit the buffer capacity that is stored in the browser at one time, and to stop the playback of the video and the data loading when the capacity is exceeded.

I found this in 'HTMLMediaElement.mozFrameBufferLength'. However, this is already a deprecated property, meaning 'the amount of storage at one time'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with a normal mp4, no. You can control what is downloaded using fragmented mp4 and media source extensions however.

Comment: Thank you!I found the answer I wanted! 